# About resizing-array implementation: Why shrinking array into half of size when it is one quarter full?

Tags: arrays

The textbook( Sedgewick and Wayne, Algorithms (4th edition))says that to shrink array, we can efficiently halve size of array s[] when it is one-quarter full instead of one-half full. But I don't know how it works?

To delete an element from an array, why can't I just copy the remaining elements to a new array? Can anyone tell me where does this "halve size of array s[]" come from? For what purpose? And the difference of efficiency between one-quarter full and one-half full?

Thank you so much !!!

Answer (score 1):

After shrinking array, which is half full, let's assume a new element is added. The array will be expanded (by 2) and will become half full again...

Now after that, if an element is removed, shrinking will occur again.

So such trivial example, when in a loop one element is added and then removed creates very bad performance.

The solution is to shrink when it is one-quoter full.

Comment: "array s[] is full" means that all s[i] are assigned some elements including null?

Comment: Correct, but it depends on the semantics and implementation.

By array here we mean some linear array based collection, like vector in C++ or ArrayList in Java or list in Python.